# Резиновое растяжение элемента по высоте

Tags: css, height

Добрый день.

Очень простой вопрос: не могу сделать растяжение элемента по высоте (ширине).
Пишу css `height:100%`, но не работает. А если явно указываю `height:500px`, то работает.
Извращаюсь с jquery, где узнаю высоту окна браузера и применяю к высоте элемента, но это как-то не очень. Хочется сделать это средствами css.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы не забыли про это?

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо - заработало. Так а в чём там проблема? Получается, что б заработало height:100% к div -надо ещё писать  height: 100%; к html, body - интересно.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин Таки высота html и body не задана. А высота дивки высчитывается относительно родительского блока.